# CentOS 7 vsftpd keeps rejecting PhpStorm FTP Connection

Tags: phpstorm, centos7, vsftpd

I recently installed vsftpd on a server at my home for local development utilizing CentOS7.  I went through the setup, and enabled passive mode, set up my ports, put my port forwarding on in my router, and then when I go to connect through PhpStorm, it rejects the connection.

I'm not sure what's going on, I've tried enabling Anonymous login, using a user, root.  Nothing seems to work.  Please let me know any information I can add.

The result from Test Connection is as follows:

> Connection to '10.0.0.110' failed.
> Connection to FTP server on "10.0.0.110" rejected.

Here are results from a FileZilla attempt.

> Status:   Connecting to 10.0.0.110:40000...
>
> Status:   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>
> Response: 500 OOPS: failed to open xferlog log
> ile:/var/log/vsftpd/vsftpd.log
>
> Error:    Critical error: Could not connect to server

Comment: 1) Try enabling extra logging and look into the log for the possible hints: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-deployment.html#collecting-logs 2) Try connecting using FileZilla -- does it work? Detailed log there can also give some hints on what may be set wrong in PhpStorm.

Comment: @LazyOne - Your provided link for PHPStorm didn't solve the issue.  Posting FileZilla Results here.  Will research them as well.

Comment: So FileZilla is also unable to connect? If so ... and esp based on "failed to open log file" part -- must be misconfiguration (access rights?) on vsftpd. Cannot help here at all (was commenting here from a PhpStorm user side of things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so here is the answer, after looking in to what @LazyOne posted.  I needed to change permissions as the first step.  `chmod 644 / 755` for files / dirs.

After that, I added in a `listen_port=40000` to my vsftpd.conf file.

Then, I added in `port_enable`, `pasv_address=<my internal ip address for my server>` and lastly, `pasv_addr_resolve=NO`, as I have a static IP on my server.

I also added additional ports to the passive settings `40000-40500`, as I've read this will allow multiple connections and will solve another error I was having.

After all of this, I opened up the ports in my server `firewall-cmd --add-port=40000-40500/tcp --permanent`, and added port forwarding in my router to allow this.

After all was said and done, I was finally able to connect to my FTP.

Hopefully this will help someone.